# How to correctly merge information from two different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem, I would like to merge the information from two dataframes into one but the information does not line up well and does not match (see pictures). Do you know how to do this? [image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
import pandas as pd 
members = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")
expeditions = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/expeditions.csv")

Everest = members[members["peak_id"]=="EVER"]
Everest = pd.merge(Everest, expeditions[['expedition_id','mois']], on='expedition_id', how='inner')
Everest_success = Everest[Everest["success"]==True]
everest_success_mois = Everest_success[["mois","success"]].groupby("mois",as_index=False).count()
essais_everest_mois = Everest[["mois","success"]].groupby("mois",as_index=False).count()
essais_everest_mois = essais_everest_mois.rename(columns={"success":"nbre_essais"})
everest_success_mois['nbre_essais'] = essais_everest_mois["nbre_essais"]
everest_success_mois["pourcentage_success_mois"] = np.where(everest_success_mois["nbre_essais"]<1, everest_success_mois["nbre_essais"], everest_success_mois["success"]/everest_success_mois["nbre_essais"]*100)
```

Comment: I think you'll need to tell more clearly about what a successful merge looks like.

Comment: Please don't use images, just the input, and expected output, not very clear what is the problem here.

Comment: I actually calculated the number of attempts per month in one dataframe and the number of successes per month in another but as there are some months with no number, it doesn't match when I merge the two

Comment: Did you try: `dfL10.rename(columns={'success': 'nbre_essais'}).merge(dfR7, on='mois', how='right'` where dfL10 is the left picture and dfR7 is the right picture.

Comment: Thank, It worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Corralien comment:

```
dfL10.rename(columns={'success': 'nbre_essais'}).merge(dfR7, on='mois', how='right')
```